What bug is this found in bedroom?
Found on the headboard of my bed
Little black bug could be a spider? Has 8 legs and what appears to be a sack. Located in Texas.
About the size of a fingernail.

Some kind of spider. Note the 8 legs.

Welcome to the Outdoors Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. We would need more photos from different angles, approximate size of the "bug" and some indication on where you are in the world to give a full ID. As @JonCuster has just commented, it is a type of spider, but there are about 51,000 known species of those worldwide.

Found in Texas and about the size of a fingernail.

It doesn't look like a brown recluse or a black widow, so it is just some harmless-to-human spider that has been helpfully chowing down on other bugs for you.

I'd hazard a guess that it is a Grey wall jumper, but the photo is far to unclear to say for sure.

@JonCuster It's an arachnid, but that doesn't make it a spider.  Adult ticks have 8 legs too.  That said, and I can't tell the species from the single photograph, I personally think it's a common spider.

Sure, but it is nothing like a North American tick morphologically. It is a spider indeed.

that sack is its abdomen, you have one of those too
